# How to use aggregate functions in linq with joins?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am writing linq query to get max count with columns from the two tables. I write sql query and it is below.

```
select MAX(p.dispalyOrder) from NCT_Process p INNER JOIN NCT_Process_Settings s ON 
p.projectId =s.projectId AND p.level=s.level
```

I tried to linq as below.

```
dbObject = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings
            join process in entityObject.NCT_Process on c.projectId equals process.projectId
            join level in entityObject.NCT_Process on c.level equals level.level
            select new settingsobject
            {
                MAX(p.dispalyOrder) to some propert of settingsobject
            }).Tolist();
```

I am not sure how to get max display order from the process table. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have foreign key relation between NCT_Process and NCT_Process_Settings table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just select the value and then call `Max` on the query.  Also to join on multiple columns you have to create anonymous classes with the columns you want to match.

```
max = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings
       join p in entityObject.NCT_Process 
       on new { c.projectId, c.level } equals new { p.projectId, p.level }
       select p.dispalyOrder).Max();
```

If you have other columns you also want to aggregate then you can do a group by on a constant value.

```
result = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings
          join p in entityObject.NCT_Process 
          on new { c.projectId, c.level } equals new { p.projectId, p.level }
          group new{c,p} on 1 into grp
          select new {
              MaxDisplayOrder = grp.Max(x => x.p.dispalyOrder),
              AvgOfSomething = grp.Avgerage(x => x.c.Something),
              MinOfASum = grp.Min(x => x.p.SomeNumber + x.c.SomeOtherNumber)
          }).Single();
```

Note the use of `Single` because an group by on a constant will only result in one row.

Or if you just want to get the max display order grouped by another column then do this

```
result = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings
          join p in entityObject.NCT_Process 
          on new { c.projectId, c.level } equals new { p.projectId, p.level }
          group p.displayOrder on c.Id into grp
          select new {
              MaxDisplayOrder = grp.Max(),
              Id = grp.Key
          }).ToList();
```

Note that the `Key` is whatever you put after the `on` and that `grp` is a collection of the values before the `on`.  And in this case there can be multiple results so you'd use `ToList` to run the query.

Comment: Thank you. How can i take otherproperties with displayorder?

Comment: If you want  other properties then you'd need to do a `group by`.  Then it depends on whether you're also aggregating them or if you actually want to group on them and only aggregate displayOrder.

Comment: May i get some examples?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole OK, I've added an example of how to aggreate multiple columns in one query.

Comment: I am getting syntext error in last answer group p.displayOrder on c.Id into grp

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole You might want to open a new quesiton about that.  Also note that I just gave an example.  I have no idea if there is an actual Id column in your NCT_Process_Settings table or not.