# How to rewrite sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to rewrite sql query to linq but can't do it myself.
The most problem for me is to get I,II and III aggregated values.
Sql query:

```
  select  o.Name,t.TypeID, SUM(e.I),SUM(e.II),SUM(e.III) from Expenditure e
  join Finance f on f.FinanceId = e.FinanceId
  join FinanceYear fy on fy.FinanceYearId = f.FinanceYearId and fy.StatusId = 1
  join Project p on p.ProjectId = fy.ProjectId
  join Organization o on o.OrganizationId = p.OrganizationId
  join Type t on t.TypeID = p.TypeID
  where fy.Year = 2018
  group by o.Name,s.TypeID
```

and what I have done so far is:

```
    var x = (from e in _db.Expenditures
             join f in _db.Finances on e.FinanceId equals f.FinanceId
             join fy in _db.FinanceYears on f.FinanceYearId equals fy.FinanceYearId and fy.StatusId = 1 // this does not work, cant join on multiple conditions?
             join p in _db.Projects on fy.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
             join o in _db.Organizations on p.OrganizationId equals o.OrganizationId
             join s in _db.Types on p.TypeId equals s.TypeId
             group new { o, s } by new { o.OrganizationId, s.TypeId }
             into grp
             select new AggModel
             {
                 OrganizationId = grp.Key.OrganizationId,
                 TypeId = grp.Key.TypeId,
                 I = ?,
                 II = ?,
                 III = ?,
             }
             );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sum a column in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349573/how-to-sum-a-column-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Can you please give more input on SUM(I), SUM(II), SUM(III) in SQL.

Comment: this values come from Expenditure table, I have edited my post @SelvaTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
group new { e, o, s } by new { o.OrganizationId, s.TypeId }
into grp
select new AggModel
{
    OrganizationId = grp.Key.OrganizationId,
    TypeId = grp.Key.TypeId,
    I = grp.Sum(a => a.e.I),
    II = grp.Sum(a => a.e.II),
    III = grp.Sum(a => a.e.III),
}
```

You'll need to adjust the right side of the lambda to navigate to the correct property.

Comment: Thanks, but multiple join condition trows an exception, please look at line number 3 in my c# code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that (had to scroll to the right).

Comment: And unfortunatelly lambda expression does not work as well. It says: does not contain a definition for 'I'

Comment: As I said, you'll have to adjust the right half of the lamba, I can't write it correctly as it's not clear from the question where I, II and III are originating from.

Comment: They come from Expenditure table

Comment: Ok, got it. I had to add "e" to 
group new { o, s, e }

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer. I don't think you can add the second part of the join clause, you could convert it into a where clause though.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use the Group by for aggregation methods.
Check the below link for more Knowledge.

[How to use aggregate functions in linq with joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976141/how-to-use-aggregate-functions-in-linq-with-joins)